# Spring Controller give always 404

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

This is my first WebApp builded using Spring and i'm going mad because when i call my RestController everytime gives me 404. I tried to use the Class/Annotaion configuration instead of the XML configuration and i think that is here that the problem lives.

Here are my config classes, pom and controller.

Sorry for the huge amount of code.

For the api call i use localhost:8080/Polito/metric

**Initailizer**

```
package com.poli.config;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class Initializer extends     AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**RootConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.poli")
@ComponentScan("com.poli")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RootConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_EJB_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    return properties;  
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO, 
            env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_EJB_NAMING_STRATEGY, 
            env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_EJB_NAMING_STRATEGY));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, 
            env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, 
            env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/personal/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
        .failureUrl("/error-login.html")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html");
}

}
```

**WebAppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.poli")
public class WebAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
       return resolver;
   }
}
```

**SecurityInitializer**

```
@Order(2)
public class SecurityInitializer extends        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**MetricRESTController**

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/metric")
public class MetricRESTController {

@Autowired
private MetricService metricService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/")
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post(@RequestBody Metric metric){
    metricService.addMetric(metric);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{uuid}")
public List<Metric> get(@PathVariable("uuid") String uuid){
    return metricService.findByUuid(uuid);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public List<Metric> get(){
    return metricService.findAllMetrics();
}
```

}

And finally **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Polito</groupId>
<artifactId>Polito</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>Polito</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- database pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring + aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't you have to annotate your controller as @Controller? (import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;)... Let me see your spring-dispatcher.xml?

Comment: With Spring 4 i think it changed in @RestController and spring dispatcher is in the configuration Classes

Comment: Nothing is mapped to `/metric`. Your get() method is mapped to `/metric/`. Also, you scan the same classes in the root context and in the wab child context. That is not correct. If you want everything to be in the child webapp context, then you can avoid the root context completely.

Comment: So i have to remove the @ComponentScan of the RootConfig? because its not working in this way..